# Generator prevent the program from receiving system signals like CTRL-C

Tags: debugging, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, networkit

I attached my code and my platform information

```py
from time import sleep

import networkit as nk
import torch
from torch_geometric.data import Data
from torch_geometric.utils.convert import from_networkit

glist = []
er_model = nk.generators.ErdosRenyiGenerator(80, 4 / 80)
for i in range(5000):
    nk_g = er_model.generate()
    pyg_e, _ = from_networkit(nk_g)
    glist.append(Data(x=torch.zeros(80, requires_grad=False), edge_index=pyg_e))

for i, g in enumerate(glist):
    sleep(1)
    print(f"iter: {i}, {g}")
```

Software:

```
System Software Overview:

  System Version: macOS 12.7.3 (21H1015)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 21.6.0
```

I am using the latest version of networkit installed via pip.

Problem and how to reproduce:

The program can not be terminated by sending ctrl-C signal. If I use NetworkX to generate graph and turn it into Networkit graph object, everything is ok. For example, if I replace `nk_g = er_model.generate()` by
`nk_g=nk.nxadapter.nx2nk(nx.erdos_renyi_graph(80, 4 / 80))`, then there is no problem at all.

Please help me locate if the problem is on networkit or torch geometrics.